# Grails access my domain User in @Secured([...])

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using spring security, and I need to get the **User** domain object in a controller.

If I call `@Secured(['principal...'])`, I get back an object of type `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser`. However, what I'm looking for is the **User** domain object I've defined in my `Config.groovy` like so:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'project.auth.User'
```

How can I do?

Comment: It would be enough if I could access to springSecurityService.currentUser in @Secured() annotation

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the springSecurityService to get the current user? In your controller, you have access to the springSecurityService. This returns a user object.

```
@Secured[...
class MyClassController {

   def springSecurityService

   def myMethod() {
       User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
   }
}
```

It's explained in [this](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html) documentation

Comment: I know, but I need access this service in @Secured anotation because you can access to this action depending of a method of User class. For instance:

class Usuario {

 transient springSecurityService

 String username
 String password
 boolean enabled
 ...
  static hasMany  = [mensajesRecibidos: Mensaje]  }
 //

Comment: I know, but I need access this service in @Secured anotation because you can access to this action depending of a method of User class. For instance:

class Usuario {
 static hasMany = [mensajesRecibidos: Mensaje]
}

and in MensajeController the show action you can access it if the Mensaje that you can show is yours, I mean something like this       
class MensajeController {

 @Secured(['currentUser.mensajesRecibidos.contains(Mensaje.get(request.params.id))'])
 def show() {